# Debugging javascript with Plunker

Tags: developer-tools, plunker

I am just starting out with Plunker, and I want to use Firefox or Chrome developer tools to debug javascript.  It looks like the javascript files get cached the first time I open them in the debugger panel.  How can I get the panel to refresh after I make changes to the javascript?  (I've tried developer tools in Chrome and Firefox, and I've tried Firebug too)

Comment: Turn caching off in your debugging tools.

Answer (score 4):

in chrome:

- open the developer tools
- open the file you want to debug: Ctrl+O and type app.js or similar
- set a breakpoint

the only tricky part is the 2nd step, since the file is in a very obscure location, fortunately Ctrl+O comes handy